# Google Cloud Platform Python 3 CURRENT_VERSION_ID

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on Google Cloud using the App Engine, porting from python2 to python3. When using the python 2 environment the CURRENT_VERSION_ID was set, I am now in the python3 environment and it is not set. Can I ask for assistance?

Comment: That variable is only available for Python 2, for Python 3 only these ones are available https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables

Comment: Please provide details on what `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` means in your application and how it is used. Are you porting an application from App Engine? More details are required to help you. Google App Engine and Compute Engine are different platforms.

Comment: CURRENT_VERSION_ID: The major and minor version of the currently running application, as "X.Y". The major version number ("X") is specified in the app's app.yaml file. The minor version number ("Y") is set automatically when each version of the app is uploaded to App Engine. On the development web server, the minor version is always "1". https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled

Comment: Please reread my comment and then update your question. App Engine and Compute Engine are different services.

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned by @Puteri, According to  [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables) the `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` environment variable from the python 2 GAE runtime is deprecated.

It has been split into `GAE_VERSION` and `GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID`  in the modern runtimes.

So, In place of the `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` environment variable you can use `GAE_VERSION` and `GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID`  in their modern runtimes.

For example:
When `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` is set to a value in the form of `a.b` you can set `GAE_VERSION='a'` and `GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID='b'`.